# Retrieve data from mysql via json array (PHP) to android not working

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to pass a json array to my android studio so i can display data retrieve from mysql server however i keep getting this error:

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value
>   [{"id":"36","reportType":"Crime","address":"Republic
>   Crescent","status":"pending"},] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be
>   converted to JSONObject

Any kind souls can help me solve this issue?

PHP Code:

```
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
$jsonObj = json_decode($input, true);
$userid = $jsonObj['userId'];

$query_rsUser = sprintf("SELECT * FROM reports  WHERE userid = %s",$userid);
$rsUser = mysqli_query($connDB, $query_rsUser);

while($row_rsUser = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsUser)) {
    $results[]=$row_rsUser;
}
echo json_encode($results);

mysqli_close($connDB);
?>
```

Java Code:

```
try {
                JSONArray resultArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("reportId");
                reports.clear();
                // Store all results into locations table layout
                for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject resultObj = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String reportid = resultObj.getString("id");
                    String reportType = resultObj.getString("reportType");
                    String address = resultObj.getString("address");
                    String status = resultObj.getString("status");
                    JSONObject ReportObj = resultObj.getJSONObject("resultObj");
                    reports.add(new ReportObj(reportid, reportType, address, status));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Looks like you have an array where you're expecting an object. Could you post the whole JSON so we can be sure?

Comment: Seems like a similar scenario to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559612/jsonarray-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject-error. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Add name of your http library and post the full java method