# how to check value in JSON

Tags: android, json

i have this JSON i want check in this JSON has `"song"` or `"fun"` and then get value and key `"price"`:

```
{
    "has_error": false,
    "response": {
        "song": {
            "price": "2000"
        },
        "jok": {
            "price": "free_for_now"
        }
    },
    "state_code": 200
}
```

Comment: Do you use json parser to parse it to object? Have you tried gson?

Comment: `JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
          JSONObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
          if (jsonObject.has("song")) {
            JSONObject music = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("song");
            String music_price = music.getString("price");
            btn_music.setText(music_price);

          }`

Comment: and this error : Value [] at response of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: have you parsed JSON Correctly?.Take a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559612/jsonarray-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject-error

Comment: oh my god, i want check if song exist return true else return false

Answer (score 4):

JSONObject class have a  **has** a method.

Ref Link : http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)

Returns true if this object has a mapping for the name. The mapping may be NULL.

for example

```
if (json.has("song")) {
     JSONObject song = jsonObject.getJSONObject("song");
 }
 if (json.has("fun")) {
     JSONObject fun = jsonObject.getJSONObject("fun");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the gson only thing you must to do is to create a java class to mapping your json string.

```
    class ModelObject{
        boolean has_error;
        Response response; // here you have the two objects: Song (with price attribute) and Jok (with price attribute); for these you must create another two classes 
        int status_code;
    }
    class Response{
        Song song;
        Jok jok;
    }

    class Song{
        String price;
    }

    class Jok{
        String price;
    }
```

Be careful to use the same name for every attribute and class name and also generate getters and setters

Then you must use import GSON in your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

Finally only thing you must to do is to use the methods from gson:

```
final Gson gson = new Gson();
//to  deserialize
ModelObject obj = gson.fromJson(yourJson, ModelObject.class);
//to serialize 
String toJson = gson.toJson(obj);
```

In obj you have all information to handle...

Comment: But if you want to check only one field on Android, why you don't send from the server side only the information you need?. Because every character mean a byte so you are sending useless information then

Answer (score 0):

use this and right work

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("response");
          if (jsonObject.has("song")) {
            JSONObject song = jsonObject.getJSONObject("song");
}
```