# JSON parsing problem in Android with Volley library

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, android-volley

I am trying to get JSON response from server and then display it in my android but failing to do so due to parsing error

Android error 
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"Result":"Login Success","User_Name:":"Ayan"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg7fS.png)

Comment: as specified in the error log, make a json array request. You are making a json object request right now

Comment: As value of data is JsonArray not JSONObject. [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559612/jsonarray-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your response, you have the field like "User_Name:" or did you wrote the response wrong?
check the second field clearly ["**User_Name:**":"Ayan"]

```
JsonObject object = new JsonObject(response);
String result = object.getString("Result");
String userName = object.getString("User_Name:");
```

It should match as like the field else it will give the exception

Comment: upvote the answer @AyanBhattacharjee If it helped .

Answer (score 0):

### try this

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
JsonObject object = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
String result = object.getString("Result");
String userName = object.getString("User_Name:");
```