# The JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Why the `JSONArray` cannot be converted to `JSONObject`

This my java :

```
private fun findsend() {
    val URL_PROFILE = "https://awalspace.com/app/imbalopunyajangandiganggu/findsend.php"
    val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PROFILE,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                try {
                    val jsonObject = JSONObject(response)
                    val jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("findsend")

                        for(i in 0 until jsonArray.length())
                        {
                            var `object` = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                            var name = `object`.getString("name").trim()
                            var no_hp = `object`.getString("no_hp").trim()
                            fetchUsers(name,no_hp)
                        }


                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error $e", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }, Response.ErrorListener { error -> Toast.makeText(this, "Error $error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }) {
    }
    val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest)

}
```

and this my JSON data

[JSON Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ijF.png)

Comment: json array and json object are 2 different things

Comment: yeah, if i just have 1 array, i can convert it to Object. but i take many array overthere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559612/jsonarray-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject-error)

Comment: Should be `val jsonArray = JSONArray(response)` because your response is an array.

Comment: you have just 1 json array with multiple json object. Check the link that I have shared above

Comment: Adding to @VivekMishra, you have to take the array first then the object by rotating in a for loop.

Comment: i have checked that, i thing my code same as what you have shared

Comment: @GyrothGames do you know how to identify which is json array and which is json object ?

Answer (score 2):

try like the following.

```
private fun findsend() {
    val URL_PROFILE = "https://awalspace.com/app/imbalopunyajangandiganggu/findsend.php"
    val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PROFILE,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                try {
                    val jsonArray = JSONArray(response) // use JSONArray instead of JSONObject
                    for(i in 0 until jsonArray.length()){
                         var jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i) // get each jsonobject from your jsonarray

                         var name = jsonObject.getString("name").trim()
                         var no_hp = jsonObject.getString("no_hp").trim()
                         fetchUsers(name,no_hp)
                    }


                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error $e", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }, Response.ErrorListener { error -> Toast.makeText(this, "Error $error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }) {
    }
    val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest)

}
```